# Faster mail () php

Tags: php

So I was creating a mailing script for my customer support
Basically what it's gonna be used for is when a user forgets their password a temporary password will be sent to their phone which they can use to reset their password

The issue I'm having while testing it goes as follows

I sent a test txt to my phone and it appeared within maybe 5mins or so

I made some tweaks for headers in order to prevent my server domain showing as the reply email

I sent another text and it's been at 20mins and still haven't received the text

I'm not sure if the headers are incorrect (if they are please let me know) but even without the headers the text is still way to slow and I need to make it faster

The text received looks like this

`(noReply) Testing

---

To report abuses or spam please follow this link: http://sp.altervista.it/s.php/a290OTB8L21vdmllSG9zdGluZy9zbXMvc21zLnBocA==`

I would also like to get rid of that line and the text below it

To be completely clear I do not want to use phpmailer or any other third party frameworks I want to keep everything nice and neatly coded in php

Here is my code (sorry it's messed up I'm on my phone doing this)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>test message</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
  <select name="carrier">
   <option value="verizon">Verizon</option>
  </select>
   <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
   </body>
  </html>

<?
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $number = $_POST['number'];
  $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

   if($carrier === "verizon"){
         $ext = "@vtext.com";
    }

    $to = $number . $ext;
     $sub = "noReply";
     $msg = $message;
     $headers = 'From: noReply@anon.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: noReply@anon.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to,$sub,$msg,$headers);

    echo "<script>alert('Messages sent')</script>";
   }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you absolutely ant ot send it via email? Those gateways aren't so reliable. Why not use a cloud communications provider like [Twilio](http://twilio.com)?

Comment: Yes this is the route were taking anything to make it more efficient would be great

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep doing it via email (which I don't reccommend), you could use [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com). It's by Rackspace and is incredibly easy to use. Your first 10k emails per month are free.

```
# Include the Autoloader (see "Libraries" for install instructions)
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('YOUR_API_KEY');
$domain = "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME";

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
    'to'      => 'Baz <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
));
```

This is copied from the docs and shows a basic way of sending mails.

Check the [Mailgun Docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) and the [PHP Repo](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php) for more extended examples.

---

If you would rather use a cloud communications provider, like [Twilio](http://twilio.com) take a look at [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/07/send-sms-with-php-and-twilio-in-60-seconds.html) great blog post about it. Here is the code sample:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php"; 
include 'settings.php'; 

$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);
$client->account->messages->create(array(
  "From" => $twilio_phone_number,
  "To" => "13123131434",
  "Body" => "Whaddup from PHP!"));
```